# How does Hibernate work with normalized databases?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

**Preliminary Info**
I'm currently trying to integrate Hibernate with my team at work. We primarily do Java web development, creating webapps that provide data to clients. Our old approach involves calling stored procedures with JDBC (on top of Oracle boxes) and storing their results in beans. However, I've heard a lot about the benefits of integrating Hibernate into a development environment like ours so I'm attempting to move away from our old habits. Note: I'm using the Hibernate JPA annotation approach due to simplicity for team adoption's sake.
**Specific Problem**
The specific issue I'm having currently is using Hibernate with normalized tables. We have a lot of schemas structured like so:

```
StateCodes (integer state_code, varchar state_name)
Businesses (integer business_id, varchar business_name, integer state_code)
```

I want to be able to have a single @Entity that has all of the "Businesses" fields, except instead of "state_code" it has "state_name". To my understanding, Hibernate treats @Entity classes as tables. The @OneToMany, @OneToOne, @ManyToOne annotations create relationships between entities, but this is a very simplistic, dictionary-like lookup and I feel like it doesn't apply here (or might be overkill).

One approach I've seen is

```
 @Formula("(select state_name from StateCodes where Businesses.state_code = state_code)")
 private String stateCode;
```

But, given Hibernate's perk of "avoiding writing raw SQL", this seems like bad practice. Not to mention, I'm *extremely* confused about how Hibernate will then treat this field. Does it get saved on a save operation? It's just defined as a query, not a column, after all.

So what is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, JPA is a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction but I don't see any restrictions not to use in in your special case. All the questions you have are discussed in basic jpa tutorials: You can map StateCode also as Entity and use it with `ManyToOne StateCode stateCode` within Business class Entity.

Comment: I've had no luck with the tutorials. I don't understand why a simple lookup for state_code would require an Entity all its own; I thought Entities just represented tables, not singular columns?

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any reason not use the standard JPA mappings in this case. Short of creating a database view and mapping an entity to that (or using the non-JPA compliant @Formula) then you will have to map as below.

Unless you are providing a means for the State to be changed then you do not need to expose the State entity to the outside world: JPA providers do not need getters/setters to be present.. Neither do you need to Map a State to Businesses:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Businesses")
public class Business{

    //define id and other fields

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "state_code")
    private State state;

    public String getStateName(){
        return state.getName();
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name="StateCodes")
public class State{

    //define id and other fields.

    @Column(name = "state_name")
    private String stateName;

    public String getStateName(){
        return stateName;
    }
}
```

Comment: On top of this writing queries to fetch a single column from the db is not the best solution in terms of performance: 1) AFAIK only Entities can be cached and 2) in most cases the db access is the bottleneck, not the "amount" of data you are trying to query.  +1